# Magento 2.3.4 - redirect url to specific store view

Tags: magento2

As the title says we would like to redirect a url to a specific store view

What we have now:

- magento1.com

  - store view EN
- magento2.com

  - store view DE

What we would like to have

- magento1.com

  - store view EN (default)
   - store view DE
- magento2.com -> redirect to store view DE on magento1.com

This is what we have now in our vhost (nginx) *of relevance to this

```
map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
    default '';
    magento2.com DE;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

    set $MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
server { 
listen 80;
server_name magento2.com;
return 301 https://magento1.com${request_uri}?___store=de;
}
```

or something like this:

```
 server { 
    listen 80;
    server_name magento2.com;
    add_header Set-Cookie store=de;
    return 301 https://magento1.com$request_uri;
    }
```

Comment: We don't want to use subdirectories. We want to have two store views (EN/DE) on one url magento1.com. This is not the issue, it's already running on a development environment. We just want our magento2.com url to redirect to magento1.com (store view DE)

Comment: see updated answer, not sure exactly what you doing there, sorry

Comment: Many thanks, I think we can make that work!